# Why is response.write in node.js not injecting html?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working through the tutorial in the beginner node book and I'm putting in this code.

```
    var body = '
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post">
        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit text"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>';
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
response.write(body);
response.end();
```

I've spaced it out, but I know I need to put it all on one line, when I do, the textarea does not appear, the html as written appears on screen.

I've spaced it out because I'm not sure if the html is correct.

What's going wrong?

Comment: _"I think I need to put it all on one line"_ - Yes, or concatenate several strings together (one per line). Have you tried `"text/html"` instead of `"text/plain"` (on the third-last line)?

Comment: right, I know, but I spaced it out just in case there was a problem with the html I had typed...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
```

To:

```
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
```

(You want the browser to interpret it as html, not plain text.)

Comment: nice, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: But there is a problem, if you do following:
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
    res.write('<b>How to render/load pages (views)? </b> <br/><br/>');
    res.write('<span style="color:#259dff">http://localhost:'+port+'/products </span>');
    res.write('will load (render)');
    res.write('<span style="color:#777">http://localhost:'+port+'/products.html</span> page/view.');
    res.end();

It does not display **http:** written in the text.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan - Well, why should it?  You don't include 'http:' in your string. In any case, that appears to be unrelated to this question, so perhaps you should post a new question of your own.

Comment: Wow thanks for that @nnnnnn. I had the same problem!